# Why would I only get a correct return for index 0

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I am working on a problem that takes a list of paint colors and gets the user to input a color name. If they match, then it says the color is found in the list; otherwise it says it is not found. If for user input, I use the first value in the list, it tells me that it is found; however, for all of the other colors, it gives the not found message.

I have checked for any variable differences between the paint color list and the input variable, I have changed variable names, tried converting input to upper and lower.

```
paint_colors = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'white', 'yellow']
color_request = input("Enter color name: ")
for color in paint_colors:
    if color_request.lower() == color:
        print("Color exists in list!")
        break
    else:
        print("Color is not in the list!")
        break
```

I would expect that by entering the word White or white into the input box, then it would tell me that it was found, but the only way I get it to return found is if I put in black.

Comment: This happens because you are applying `break` on else case also. so the loop only runs once

Comment: remove `break` from the loop, the code will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `break` statement is causing the problem. You can try this:

```
paint_colors = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'white', 'yellow']
color_request = input("Enter color name: ")
for color in paint_colors:
    if color_request.lower() == color:
        print("Color exists in list!")
        break
else:
    print("Color is not in the list!")
```

Using one more variable in a different way:

```
paint_colors = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'white', 'yellow']
color_request = input("Enter color name: ")
found = 0
for color in paint_colors:
    if color_request.lower() == color:
        found = 1
        break
if found:
    print("Color exists in list!")
else:
    print("Color is not in the list!")
```

Using `in` operator:

```
paint_colors = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'white', 'yellow']
color_request = input("Enter color name: ")

if color_request in paint_colors:
    print("Color exists in list!")
else:
    print("Color is not in the list!")
```

Comment: You might want to use a `raw_input` instead of just `input`. Otherwise, users will get an exception if they don't warp the value in **""**; i.e _"white"_.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with an example?

Comment: `color_request = input("Enter color name: ") File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'white' is not defined`

Comment: I've tried the same code, it worked fine without any issues!

Comment: This I think only happens on Python 2.7 platform. I believe it's changed on the 3.x.

Comment: Thanks @TaohidulIslam. That works. I also like the code with the one extra variable, found, in it. One more question though. Why does bringing the else statement out of the loop, correct the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The second `break` is redundant, because when color doesn't match first index, you are breaking from the loop prematurely:

```
paint_colors = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'white', 'yellow']
color_request = input("Enter color name: ")
for color in paint_colors:
    if color_request.lower() == color:
        print("Color exists in list!")
        break
else:
    print("Color is not in the list!")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can set a flag `colour_found` which keeps track of whether we found the colour in the list or not. If we found the color then we can exit the loop.

```
paint_colors = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'white', 'yellow']
color_request = input("Enter color name: ")
colour_found = False
for color in paint_colors:
    if color_request.lower() == color:
        colour_found = True
        break



if colour_found:
    print("Color exists in list!")
else:
    print("Color is not in the list!")
```